# How to Animate Switching Buttons in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a button on navigationbar called Map and List

When Map is pressed I do

```
- (IBAction)Map:(id)sender {
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =self.List;
    [BNUtilitiesQuick AnimateSwitchingWithParent:SwitchViews From:theTable To:GoogleMapController.view];

}

- (IBAction)List:(id)sender {
    self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =self.Map;
    [BNUtilitiesQuick AnimateSwitchingWithParent:SwitchViews From:GoogleMapController.view To:theTable];

}
```

Now, curiously, rather than setting `self.tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =self.Map;` and make the button split in a jiffy, I think I would like to animate that switch.

How would I do so?

Also how would I animate pushing and poping view to navigation controller? How do I animate users switching **tabBar** item?

Comment: Geez, use lower-case names for methods!

Answer (score 1):

If you check out the UITabBar documentation: [UITabBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITabBar)

```
- (void)setItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Try making an array of the new tab bar items you want, and set it to the UITabBar

```
// Assuming "tabBar" is a UITabBar, probably part of a UITabBarController
// Assuming "newItem" is a new UITabBarItem containing the new buttons you want
// animate in.

NSArray* newItemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:newItem,nil];
[tabBar setItems:newItemArray animated:YES];

// This should work, and you can include more than just one new item for multiple
// buttons on the tab bar.
```

Hope that works for you!